# Start debugging on C# startup project in native-only mode

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a MSVC2013 solution with C# (managed) and C++ (native) projects. One **C# project is set as startup** project. I want to start this project with debugging, which is usually achieved in devenv by simply pressing F5.

However, I want to start debugger in **native-only** mode (i.e. **no managed debugging**). I cannot achieve this behavior by changing settings of C# project: it only has an option "Enable native code debugging", which allows to enable or disable native debugging. The only standard way I know is to start application without debugging, and then attach to process with only native debugging chosen.

Is there a way to automate this process? Ideally, pressing one button should be enough to start native-only debugging. Perhaps some extension could simplify this task.

---

*P.S.* I have bumped into a nasty bug in mixed mode debugging, which breaks debugging completely in my case. This bug itself is **not** the topic of the question, it just explains why native-only debugging with C# startup project may be useful (and is useful to me personally).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not very clear why you can't simply use Project > Properties > Debug tab > tick "Enable native code debugging".  If you use VS2012 and up then do beware that you have to disable the new managed debugging engine, it is no longer compatible with C++/CLI code.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".

But you can achieve what you want, simply select one of the native code projects as your startup project.  Right-click > Set as Startup Project.  And you must select the startup EXE, Right-click > Properties > Debugging > Command, change it to the C# executable.  Breakpoints become active (colored solid red) as soon as the C# code loads your DLL.

Comment: Sounds like a simple solution I must have invented myself =) Thank you for the answer!
I'll look into "Use Managed Compatibility Mode", perhaps it would fix all the issues I'm trying to circumvent.

Comment: Depending on your project, attaching to a running instance of your process is a solution. This is what I usually do for my projects mixing C++ and C# (and sometimes C++/CLI) : when attaching, you can easily force "native only" as it is available as checkboxes.

Comment: The "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" setting really fixed all the problems I had! I was going to post a large question begging for debug help, with graphs, tables, bounty and tons of text... now the problem is fixed without even being uncovered.
In my case, behavior was very weird: after a COM call from C++ project debugger completely lost thread of execution (breakpoints no longer hit anywhere, weird messages in Output).
Perhaps I should still post the big question with exact symptoms as community wiki (with your answer)?

Comment: I have posted the full question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308480/visual-studio-debugger-stops-hitting-breakpoints-in-mixed-debugging-mode/33308481).